# Interact not working from within Expect Script

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I have the following expect script within a bash script and I'm unsure as to why the interact command is not working.

```
expect <<-EOS
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set timeout $EXP_TIMEOUT
    send_user "\n The timeout being used is $EXP_TIMEOUT \n"
    send_user "\nLogging into remote host via SSH:\n"
    spawn ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=$SSH_TIMEOUT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ${hostname}
    expect "*assword*"
    send -- "$secret\r"
    expect {
            "*assword*" {
                    send \x03
                    puts "\nIncorrect Password\n"
            }
            "$prompt" {
                    send -- "/usr/seos/bin/sesu - $user\r"
                    expect "*assword*"
                    send -- "$secret\r"
                    expect "$prompt"
                    send -- "id\r"
                    expect "$prompt"
                    send -- "hostname -s\r"
                    interact
            }
    }
    expect eof
```

EOS
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) with which you can write Expect all in shell code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`interact` can't let the user enter data via stdin because you are already redirecting stdin for the here document.

Instead, you can save your here document with all expansions to a variable, and then pass that to `-c`. Here's a simplified example:

```
script=$(cat << EOF
    spawn vi
    send "iHello $(hostname)"
    interact
EOF
)
expect -c "$script"
```

Comment: This is at the complexity where putting the expect code in its own script file is a good plan. Not having to deal with multiple levels of quoting at once (bash & tcl at the same time!) is worth the extra pain of needing to pass arguments explicitly instead of via substitution.